# How to debug Behave BDD scenario using python debugger and Visual studio Code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-behave

I use Visual studio code to edit my Behave scenarios and Python steps.

I have been able to run my steps using the Visual Studio Code console.

I have not been able to configure the python debugger to debug my Python scripts when they are called by behave.

How can I use the Visual Studion Code Python debugger with Behave.exe ?
What would be the debug configuration parameters?[visual studio code launch.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AXMT.png)

Answer (score 13):

Add configuration for start debugin current features:

```
{
    "name": "Python: Behave current file",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "module": "behave",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "args": [
        "${file}"
    ]
},
```

Comment: This worked great, thank you so much! (Works on MacOS) just keep in mind you have to launch it on the .feature file - which is odd, but makes sense

Comment: Thanks, this approach works for me (Ubuntu 22.04,VS Code).
Configure launch.json and save it.
Then move to the .feature file and click F5 for debugging.

Comment: If you don't want to have the .feature file as the active editor every time you trigger the debug session, you can modify the `"args"` field to pass the path to the directory where the feature file is: `"args": ["path/to/directory/with/feature/files"]`

Answer (score 6):

Use the following `launch.json` settings to run a single Behave test by selecting the scenario name and press `F5` or Start Debugging button.

```
    {
        "name": "Python: Behave",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "module": "behave",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "args": [
            "--no-capture",
            "--no-capture-stderr",
            "--no-skipped",
            "${file}",
            "--tags=${selectedText}"
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I succeeded to debug my python code by calling the Python main of behave using the following Launch.json:

```
 {

  "name": "Python: Terminal (integrated)",

  "type": "python",

  "request": "launch",

  "program": "C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\Lib\\site-packages\\behave\\__main__.py",

  "console": "integratedTerminal",

  "cwd":"${workspaceFolder}\\Drivers_Features"

 },
```

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can see that differs between your and my `launch.json` setup is that I use `args` to set the test directory instead of switching `cwd`:

```
{
    "name": "Python: Behave (.venv)",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/bin/behave",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "args": [
        "tests/integration"
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a conda environment with behave installed on the %path% using pip.

In my environment I also have a **tests/** subdirectory which I explicitly use cwd to change path before executing behave.

This is the excerpt from my launch.json

```
    {
        "name": "Python: Behave",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/tests",
        "args": ["-m", "behave"]
    },
```

What I'm effectively trying to achieve here is something resembling the following steps on the command line:

1. `cwd /path/to/workspace/folder/tests`
2. `python -mbehave`

I have the VSCode for Python extension installed which recognizes my conda virtual environment.

I am also running this on a Windows box, so your mileage may vary on Linux or Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this configuration

```
{
        "name": "Behave",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "module": "behave",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/behave"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like [lindstromhenrik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52811512/11657671)'s answer as it doesn't need to change the current working directory.

For other Windows users (as the user asking the question was), the behave .exe program is in the "*Scripts*" folder:

```
{
    "name": "Python: Behave (.venv)",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\.venv\\Scripts\\behave.exe",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "args": [
      "tests"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Behave: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "behave",
            "args": ["features/featureDef/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.feature"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Behave @testThis",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "behave",
            "args": [
               "--tags= testThis",
               "--no-skipped"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Behave Run ALL",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "behave"
        }


    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add json. file:
add @wip tag in gerkin scenrio.
select debug in Behave Current Scenerio
select Gerkin scenerio and run debug.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Behave Run ALL",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "behave",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {
                "BASE_DIR": "${workspaceFolder}"
                   },
            "args":[
                "--no-capture",
                "--no-capture-stderr",
                "*.feature"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Behave specific tags",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "behave",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {
                "BASE_DIR": "${workspaceFolder}"
                   },
            "args":[
                "GUI/CustomerWebApp",
                "--tags=@US1003",
                "--no-capture",
                "--no-capture-stderr"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Behave Current file",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "behave",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {
                "BASE_DIR": "${workspaceFolder}"
                   },
            "args":[
                "${file}",
                "-w",
                "--no-capture",
                "--no-capture-stderr"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Behave Selected Scenario",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "behave",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {
                "BASE_DIR": "${workspaceFolder}"
                   },
            "args":[
                "${file}",
                "-n",
                "${selectedtext}",
                "--no-capture",
                "--no-capture-stderr"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```